# View navigation issue in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have three pages **HomePage,AddUser,ViewUser**.I go to **addUser** page by clicking a command button

code for going to addUser page.

```
<p:commandButton value="Add User" id="btn"
                        styleClass="home-button" action="addUser?faces-redirect=true"/>
```

I am going back to **HomePage** by clicking on link

```
<a href="Home.xhtml" style="float:left"><img src="images/back.png" ></img>
```

From home page I am going to **viewUser** page by clicking on command button

code for going to viewUser page.

```
<p:commandButton value="View Users"
                        styleClass="home-button"  action="viewUser?faces-redirect=true" />
```

If i keep swithing between diffrent screens like this more than 10 times,Then my web app hangs.after clicking on button nothing happens.Even page does not reload it hangs.May i know why it is happening & how to get solution for this.

Comment: If you do not receive any error neither on the server side nor on the client-side for sure, then it is likely to be the browser's own problem which may propagate to the platform you are using (a combination of Operating System and Hardware). Try using different browsers alternatively.

Comment: As Tiny indicated, be sure to check for server (check the log) and client-side error (check Chrome Developer tools) for error messages. In Chrome, go to the "Network" tab and check the response of the POST or GET that occurs when you click the link.

Comment: i tried on different browsers i am still getting the problem

Comment: Davids asked way more than what Tiny asked. Please do what he requested. To get serious help, *you* have to narrow things down in many cases

Comment: Going to network tab i don't see any request further.Is this the case of database connection issue ?

Comment: Network tab is clientside, database is server side (why this strange question?) If the server side database was an issue, you should have seen requests. But if things stop working, that can be because of an error in earlier requests (including in network responses) you still have to digg into this further yourself. And run your app in jsf development mode. Might help to.

Comment: Actually after a certain everything stops.I don't see any logs on neither on server side nor on client side.